# How to keep to select boxes in sync based on zustand store value in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, zustand

One of the requirements for an web app i'm working on is to have multiple languages, to implement this i'm using i18n and zustand to store the new set language and have it accessible in any component/page.

I have two select boxes, one in the navbar and another in the footer of the page to set language.
The problem is, when i set a new language in one select box, the page is translated, but i want the other select box to have it's default value as the new language set(picking it up from zustand store), so in both the navbar and the footer would have the same default value and be synced whenever one has changed.

For example the page starts with portuguese, but if i change it to english, the other select box still has the old value(portuguese), altho it's default value is set to the value in zustand store.

I've thought and tried couple solutions like storing the language in local storage and then get it or creating a function that runs always but none worked for me. Also wasn't alble to find anyonw with a similiar problem when researching it.

Bellow follows the code for the navbar component, the footer component and the zustand store.

Navbar:

```
import {
  BtnWrapper,
  LanguageSelector,
  Link,
  Logo,
  NavBar,
  NavListItem,
  NavlinkItemHighlighted,
  Navlist,
  RegisterAndLoginButton,
} from "./NavbarWithoutLogin.styles";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { useWebSiteLanguageStore } from "../../../store/WebSiteLanguageStore";

export const Nav = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation()
  const websiteLanguageStore = useWebSiteLanguageStore()

  return (
    <>
      <NavBar>
        <Logo>logo</Logo>
        <Navlist>
          <NavlinkItemHighlighted>
            <span>{t("navbarLink1")}</span>
          </NavlinkItemHighlighted>
          <NavListItem>
            <Link>{t("navbarLink2")}</Link>
          </NavListItem>
          <NavListItem>
            <Link>{t("navbarLink3")}</Link>
          </NavListItem>
          <NavListItem>
            <Link>{t("navbarLink4")}</Link>
          </NavListItem>
          <NavListItem>
            <Link>{t("navbarLink5")}</Link>
          </NavListItem>
          <NavListItem>
            <RegisterAndLoginButton>
              {t("navbarLoginButton")}
            </RegisterAndLoginButton>
            |
            <RegisterAndLoginButton>
              {t("navbarRegisterButton")}
            </RegisterAndLoginButton>
          </NavListItem>
        </Navlist>
        <BtnWrapper>
          <LanguageSelector
            defaultValue={websiteLanguageStore.currentlySelectedLanguage}
            onChange={(e) =>
              websiteLanguageStore.changeCurrentlySelectedLanguage(
                e.target.value
              )
            }
          >
            <option value="pt">{t("navbarLanguageSelectorOption1")}</option>
            <option value="fr">{t("navbarLanguageSelectorOption2")}</option>
            <option value="en">{t("navbarLanguageSelectorOption3")}</option>
            <option value="de">{t("navbarLanguageSelectorOption4")}</option>
            <option value="tt">{t("navbarLanguageSelectorOption5")}</option>
            <option value="es">{t("navbarLanguageSelectorOption6")}</option>
          </LanguageSelector>
        </BtnWrapper>
      </NavBar>
    </>
  );
};
```

Footer:

```
import {
  LinkBox,
  LinkBoxUlLi,
  Footer,
  Copyright,
  CopyrightText,
  HelpCenterBox,
  LanguageSelector,
} from "./PageFooter.styles";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faCopyright } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import {
  faFacebook,
  faLinkedin,
  faSquareInstagram,
  faYoutube,
} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { useWebSiteLanguageStore } from "../../../store/WebSiteLanguageStore";

export const PageFooter = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const websiteLanguageStore = useWebSiteLanguageStore();

  return (
    <>
      <Footer>
        <div>
          <b>{t("footerFistSectionTitle")}</b>
          <LinkBox>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <a>{t("footerFirstSectionOptions1")}</a>
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <a>{t("footerFirstSectionOptions12")}</a>
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <a>{t("footerFirstSectionOptions13")}</a>
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
          </LinkBox>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>{t("footerSecondSectionTitle")}</b>
          <LinkBox>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <a>{t("footerSecondSectionOption")}</a>
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <a>{t("footerSecondSectionOption2")}</a>
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <a>{t("footerSecondSectionOption3")}</a>
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <a>{t("footerSecondSectionOption4")}</a>
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
          </LinkBox>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>{t("footerThirdSectionTitle")}</b>
          <LinkBox>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <a>{t("footerThirdSectionOption")}</a>
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <a>{t("footerThirdSectionOption2")}</a>
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
          </LinkBox>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>{t("footerThirdSectionTitle")}</b>
          <LinkBox>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <HelpCenterBox>
                {t("footerFourthSectionHelpCenterBox")}
              </HelpCenterBox>
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
          </LinkBox>
          <span>{t("footerFourthSectionLanguageSelector")}: </span>
          <LanguageSelector
            defaultValue={websiteLanguageStore.currentlySelectedLanguage}
            onChange={(e) => {
              websiteLanguageStore.changeCurrentlySelectedLanguage(
                e.target.value
              );
            }}
          >
            <option value="pt">{t("footerLanguageSelectorOption1")}</option>
            <option value="fr">{t("footerLanguageSelectorOption2")}</option>
            <option value="en">{t("footerLanguageSelectorOption3")}</option>
            <option value="de">{t("footerLanguageSelectorOption4")}</option>
            <option value="tt">{t("footerLanguageSelectorOption5")}</option>
            <option value="es">{t("footerLanguageSelectorOption6")}</option>
          </LanguageSelector>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>{t("footerFollowUsSectionTitle")}</b>
          <LinkBox>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <a>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebook} size="xl" />
              </a>{" "}
              <a>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSquareInstagram} size="xl" />
              </a>{" "}
              <a>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faYoutube} size="xl" />{" "}
                <a>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLinkedin} size="xl" />
                </a>{" "}
              </a>{" "}
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
          </LinkBox>
        </div>
      </Footer>
      <Copyright>
        <CopyrightText>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCopyright} /> {t("footerCopyWrightText")}{" "}
        </CopyrightText>
      </Copyright>
    </>
  );
};
```

zustand store:

```
import { create } from "zustand";
import i18n from "../i18n";

type WebSiteLanguageSettings = {
  currentlySelectedLanguage: string
  changeCurrentlySelectedLanguage: (language: string) => void
}

export const useWebSiteLanguageStore = create<WebSiteLanguageSettings>(
  (set) => {
    return {
      currentlySelectedLanguage: i18n.language,
      changeCurrentlySelectedLanguage(language) {
        i18n.changeLanguage(language)
        this.currentlySelectedLanguage = language
      },
    };
  }
);
```

I'm using styled-components, if the style files are needed i can post it here.

Comment: When state is involved, make component as controlled. So do not use defaultValue, use value in select. Second when you want to update the state in zustand, use `set` function to update it. Third, create a component for `LanguageSelector` and use it in navbar and footer.

Answer (score 0):

I had never used zustand befor,but I saw it's document ,if you lost the 'set' function?

```js
import { create } from 'zustand'

const useBearStore = create((set) => ({
  bears: 0,
  increasePopulation: () => set((state) => ({ bears: state.bears + 1 })),
  removeAllBears: () => set({ bears: 0 }),
}))
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on thiss? I didn't understand what you mean by "loosing" the set function

Comment: export const useWebSiteLanguageStore = create<WebSiteLanguageSettings>(
  (set) => {
    return {
      currentlySelectedLanguage: i18n.language,
      changeCurrentlySelectedLanguage(language) {
       i18n.changeLanguage(language);
       set({ currentlySelectedLanguage : language})
      },
    };
  }
);

Answer (score 0):

To keep two select boxes in sync based on zustand store value in react, you need to use the same selector function for both of them and pass a shallow equality function as the second argument to the useStore hook.

```
import create from 'zustand'
import shallow from 'zustand/shallow'

const useStore = create (set => ( {
  options: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
  selected: 'A',
  setSelected: value => set (state => ( { selected: value })),
}))

const selectOptions = state => ( { options: state.options, selected: state.selected })


const SelectBox = () => {
  
  const { options, selected, setSelected } = useStore (selectOptions, shallow)

 
  const handleChange = event => {
    setSelected (event.target.value)
  }


  return (
    <select value={selected} onChange={handleChange}>
      {options.map (option => (
        <option key={option} value={option}>
          {option}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  )
}


const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <SelectBox />
      <SelectBox />
    </div>
  )
}
```

This code will render two select boxes that are always in sync with each other and the store.

Comment: I'm using typescript in this project, so to try your solution i had to change couple things, like giving types to some declarations i believe this might have something with the outcome i had as when i solved all the errors and implemented it to my solution i didin't manage to make it work. When destructuring the useStore values it complains the useStore is depreciated, also when calling setSelect in complains that the function "setSelect does not exist on type selected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of how good or efficient is this, but i found a solution for this problem. Using this code i managed to make the two select boxes synced whenever a language change is set to the website.

Also took couple tips from everyone answering and commenting, so thanks all. If any one as tips to improve this and prevent bugs or problems in the future please be welcome.

I was thinking if i really needed zustand for this, from a point of if i could implement this without using it but still be good, i'm a beginner in react and also state managment solutions like zustand seems to be appropiate to more complex state managment problems.

I created an helper function setLanguage, which takes the new select value when onChange, and sets the new language with i18n.changeLanguage and stores the language in localStorage.
In the i18n definition function i put it to pick the language from localStorage or english as default and fallback too.

Heres the code:

```
import i18n from "../i18n";

export const setLanguage = (language: string) => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(language);
    localStorage.setItem("language", language)
    window.location.reload();
};
```

```
import {
  BtnWrapper,
  Link,
  Logo,
  NavBar,
  NavListItem,
  NavlinkItemHighlighted,
  Navlist,
  RegisterAndLoginButton,
} from "./NavbarWithoutLogin.styles";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { setLanguage } from "../../../helpers/setLanguage";
import { LanguageSelectorSelect } from "../LanguageSelector/LanguageSelector";

export const Nav = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <>
      <NavBar>
        <Logo>Ilha</Logo>
        <Navlist>
          <NavlinkItemHighlighted>
            <span>{t("navbar.navbarLink1")}</span>
          </NavlinkItemHighlighted>
          <NavListItem>
            <Link>{t("navbar.navbarLink2")}</Link>
          </NavListItem>
          <NavListItem>
            <Link>{t("navbar.navbarLink3")}</Link>
          </NavListItem>
          <NavListItem>
            <Link>{t("navbar.navbarLink4")}</Link>
          </NavListItem>
          <NavListItem>
            <Link>{t("navbar.navbarLink5")}</Link>
          </NavListItem>
          <NavListItem>
            <RegisterAndLoginButton>
              {t("navbar.navbarLoginButton")}
            </RegisterAndLoginButton>
            |
            <RegisterAndLoginButton>
              {t("navbar.navbarRegisterButton")}
            </RegisterAndLoginButton>
          </NavListItem>
        </Navlist>
        <BtnWrapper>
          <LanguageSelectorSelect
            value={String(localStorage.getItem("language"))}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setLanguage(e.target.value);
            }}
          >
            <option value="pt">{t("navbar.navbarLanguageSelectorOption1")}</option>
            <option value="fr">{t("navbar.navbarLanguageSelectorOption2")}</option>
            <option value="en">{t("navbar.navbarLanguageSelectorOption3")}</option>
            <option value="de">{t("navbar.navbarLanguageSelectorOption4")}</option>
            <option value="tt">{t("navbar.navbarLanguageSelectorOption5")}</option>
            <option value="es">{t("navbar.navbarLanguageSelectorOption6")}</option>
          </LanguageSelectorSelect>
        </BtnWrapper>
      </NavBar>
    </>
  );
};
```

```
import {
  LinkBox,
  LinkBoxUlLi,
  Footer,
  Copyright,
  CopyrightText,
  HelpCenterBox,
} from "./PageFooter.styles";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faCopyright } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import {
  faFacebook,
  faLinkedin,
  faSquareInstagram,
  faYoutube,
} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { setLanguage } from "../../../helpers/setLanguage";
import { LanguageSelectorSelect } from "../LanguageSelector/LanguageSelector";

export const PageFooter = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <>
      <Footer>
        <div>
          <b>{t("footerSection.footerFistSectionTitle")}</b>
          <LinkBox>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <a>{t("footerSection.footerFirstSectionOptions1")}</a>
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <a>{t("footerSection.footerFirstSectionOptions12")}</a>
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <a>{t("footerSection.footerFirstSectionOptions13")}</a>
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
          </LinkBox>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>{t("footerSection.footerSecondSectionTitle")}</b>
          <LinkBox>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <a>{t("footerSection.footerSecondSectionOption")}</a>
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <a>{t("footerSection.footerSecondSectionOption2")}</a>
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <a>{t("footerSection.footerSecondSectionOption3")}</a>
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <a>{t("footerSection.footerSecondSectionOption4")}</a>
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
          </LinkBox>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>{t("footerSection.footerThirdSectionTitle")}</b>
          <LinkBox>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <a>{t("footerSection.footerThirdSectionOption")}</a>
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <a>{t("footerSection.footerThirdSectionOption2")}</a>
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
          </LinkBox>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>{t("footerSection.footerThirdSectionTitle")}</b>
          <LinkBox>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <HelpCenterBox>
                {t("footerSection.footerFourthSectionHelpCenterBox")}
              </HelpCenterBox>
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
          </LinkBox>
          <span>
            {t("footerSection.footerFourthSectionLanguageSelector")}:{" "}
          </span>
          <LanguageSelectorSelect
            value={String(localStorage.getItem("language"))}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setLanguage(e.target.value);
            }}
          >
            <option value="pt">
              {t("footerSection.footerLanguageSelectorOption1")}
            </option>
            <option value="fr">
              {t("footerSection.footerLanguageSelectorOption2")}
            </option>
            <option value="en">
              {t("footerSection.footerLanguageSelectorOption3")}
            </option>
            <option value="de">
              {t("footerSection.footerLanguageSelectorOption4")}
            </option>
            <option value="tt">
              {t("footerSection.footerLanguageSelectorOption5")}
            </option>
            <option value="es">
              {t("footerSection.footerLanguageSelectorOption6")}
            </option>
          </LanguageSelectorSelect>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>{t("footerSection.footerFollowUsSectionTitle")}</b>
          <LinkBox>
            <LinkBoxUlLi>
              <a>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebook} size="xl" />
              </a>{" "}
              <a>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSquareInstagram} size="xl" />
              </a>{" "}
              <a>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faYoutube} size="xl" />{" "}
                <a>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLinkedin} size="xl" />
                </a>{" "}
              </a>{" "}
            </LinkBoxUlLi>
          </LinkBox>
        </div>
      </Footer>
      <Copyright>
        <CopyrightText>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCopyright} />{" "}
          {t("footerSection.footerCopyWrightText")}{" "}
        </CopyrightText>
      </Copyright>
    </>
  );
};
```